# C++ - An if statement checking strings improperly

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string questionOneAnswer;
string questionTwoAnswer;
string questionThreeAnswer;


class quizAshton{
    public:
        string question1(){
            cout << "What is your favorite food?" << endl;
            cin >> questionOneAnswer;
            return questionOneAnswer;
        }
        string question2(){
            cout << "What is the name of someone you hate?" << endl;
            cin >> questionTwoAnswer;
            return questionTwoAnswer;
        }
        string question3(){
            cout << "Hi! (yes or no)" << endl;
            cin >> questionThreeAnswer;
            return questionThreeAnswer;
        }

};

int main()
{
    quizAshton ashtonAnswers;

    ashtonAnswers.question1();
    ashtonAnswers.question2();
    ashtonAnswers.question3();

    if (questionThreeAnswer!= "yes" or "no"){
    cout << "I asked for a yes or no! You betrayed me!" << endl;
    return 0;
    }

    cout << "APPARENTLY your favorite food is " << questionOneAnswer << "... I guess I wouldn't really believe that unless it was eaten by " << questionTwoAnswer << "and is the cat ready...: " << questionThreeAnswer << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The "if" statement under main, even if I put yes or no or an invalid answer, will still continue the if statement. (no matter what I put, it will still display the message inside the if statement).

```
if (questionThreeAnswer!= "yes" or "no"){
        cout << "I asked for a yes or no! You betrayed me!" << endl;
        return 0;
        }
```

I know this is a simple fix, but i'm not entirely sure what. I'm a bit of a noobie. Also, this may or may not be the most efficient way of doing what i'm trying to do, but this is mostly for practice.

Comment: first guess, carriege return ( enter ) is also in your stored string... anyway, you cant do `questionThreeAnswer!= "yes" or "no"` ( SQL? ) it has to be `if( questionthreeAnswer != "yes" || questionthreeanswer != "no" )`

Comment: if (questionThreeAnswer!= "yes" || questionThreeAnswer!= "no"){
    cout << "I asked for a yes or no! You betrayed me!" << endl;
    return 0;
    } still gives me the message even if I put yes or no

Comment: you should use "&&". because you want the message to show when its NOT "yes" AND NOT "no"

Answer (score 2):

`if (questionThreeAnswer!= "yes" or "no")`
should be
`if ((questionThreeAnswer != "yes") &&  (questionThreeAnswer != "no"))`

Also I suggest you not to forget about cases of letters in input, there should be something like `equalsIgnoreCase()` or `toUpper()` in std library to check answers ignoring case.

Comment: no need for parenthesis though. 'if(questionThreeAnswer != "yes" && questionThreeAnswer != "no")' is enough :P

Comment: Thank you, sir! As well as everybody else that commented.

Comment: @Litari: There is no need, but it makes the intent way more clear and doesn't hurt readability.

Comment: @Litari, it's always good to use parenthesis, no need to remember about operator priorities when reading the code. And it allows to avoid bugs when you was wrong with priorities when writing the code, this kind of bugs may be difficult to locate

Comment: @user1550744: I dont know if you are familiar with how SO works, but since you seem new too the site I might as well let you know: If you found that an answer solved your question, press the little check-mark next to the answer. That way other people will know that the answer with the checkmark solved it. (and SpongeBobFan will recieve rep :P)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (questionThreeAnswer != "yes" and questionThreeAnswer != "no")
```

Comment: should be "&&" instead of "and"

Comment: @Litari In C++, `and` is the same as `&&`. There's no keyword `and` in  C though.

Answer (score 1):

What you are checking is equivalent to the following

```
if ( (questionThreeAnswer!= "yes") or ("no") )
```

or in more traditional c++

```
if ( (questionThreeAnswer!= "yes") || ("no") )
```

What you want is

```
if ( questionThreeAnswer != "yes" && questionThreeAnswer != "no" )
```